# Canvas Drawing with browser compatibility

Tags: cross-browser, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-10

In my application, I created Canvas and started to draw lines, rectangles and drawing with pencil. Everything works good on Firefox and Chrome(with latest versions). The Problem with IE only. While I draw on canvas with pencil, it was not draw at mouse pointing spot (drawn little bit top of the cursor point). I used  `IE version 10` only. Need to add any code for browser compatibility issue on IE 10??

**Note:** It was working on IE 9 but, If I changed browser version to IE 10 Compatibility View, It was showing `This Browser doesn't support Html 5. Try with higher version`

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Canvas draws fine for me in IE-10, so the problem is code specific.  Do you have code to show us?

Comment: show the code where you tells that the browser is not supported

Comment: You should post the code which converts the mouse event coordinates to canvas coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

IE-10 compatability view makes IE-10 compatable with earlier version of IE. Canvas does not work with versions before IE-9. Using  explorercanvas at http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/downloads/list allows canvas to be used with earlier versions.

Does your script work in IE-10 with compatability not switched on? It should do.